# Social authentication process flow

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have an application with user registration using email & password. I am trying to work out the process flow for adding social authentication providers.

As an example using LinkedIn, login & register process both seem identical:

```
Get authentication token from LinkedIn
If successful, get id, email, firstname, lastname from LinkedIn.
Try find a user in our user table with email or linkedin id.
If no user create, storing linkedin id, email, firstname, lastname
Login to our site.
```

1. Is this the most suitable flow?
2. What to do with password in our user table when the user is created? The user later wishes to login with his email & password rather than LinkedIn.
3. Twitter does not provide access to email so can't follow above process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work this out with associated social accounts relationship

**Is this the most suitable flow?**

- yes it's most common, but to adopt many provides you can do like , when ever user creates account (with any process Password or Social Providers) then you can store that info like loginTypes ( Pwd, Twitter, FB) etc , it's like array

**What to do with password in our user table when the user is created? The user later wishes to login with his email & password rather than LinkedIn.**

- you can support that by giving option to user to setup password if they need , then update the login types to include password as one of types

So when the user tries to login with password , you can find the account by email and see if password is added in login types , if so the proceed with password check else reject

**Twitter does not provide access to email so can't follow above process.**

You can store Twitter unique id returned for the user in DB and use that for checking next time

Hope that clarifies you!